# Retrieve an object using Collections.binarySearch

Tags: java, collections, binary-search

I declared a POJO class with `id, Name, age, contactNumber and Address` attributes. I declared  all getters and setters. Now I am using `HashMap<String, POJO_CLASS>`. By default I sorts these values by `Name` attribute. Now my need is to search an object by id, and that method should return an object (which is stored in HashMap as value). So how can I use `Collections.binarySearch()` for this requirement.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/WritingYourownComparator.htm  Bookmarked

Comment: Is this about efficiently finding the object by id, or specifically about `binarySearch`?

Comment: What's the type of id, and what field of your object are you using as the key of your map?

Comment: Actually I have more than 500 objects of my POJO class, and I have to search an object by id, so thought this will be best way. Is any other way? Please guide me if other way exists.

Comment: Also what do you mean when you say you sort these values by name? HashMaps don't sort their contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better question is why would you want to. HashMap lookups are going to be very fast, O(1) time whereas binary searches are going to take O(lg(N)) time on Lists that have random access abilities (ArrayList).

If you *really* want to use binary searches then you need to store your objects in a list (ArrayList probably) and have that list sorted and then call `Collections.binarySearch(list, value)`.

Answer (score 2):

500 objects is not that many, so I would just put them in a second HashMap keyed on the id.

Answer (score 1):

If you need fast lookup by both name and by id, you're going to need to permanently store the POJOs in two different data structures.  In this case, building a second HashMap off of id, would give you the best performance.

This may be unnecesarily complex if the map is not that large or lookup by id is a relatively infrequent occurance.  In that case I would just do a linear search through the HashMap.